# Conditional rendering within loops in React JS

Tags: reactjs, loops, rendering

I have data coming from an external API that I am trying to display in a table. The data comes back with date time stamps.

I'd like to render the data in a table, but with an extra row in that displays the date when the date changes.

What I've tried

- I've attempted updating a lastDate prop value.
- I've attempted conditional rendering with the (condition) ? expected : other syntax and a variable in the render() method.
- I can't figure out how to keep track of the current date variable and update it on every loop iteration.
- I've tried splitting the DateRow and the DataRow into seperate components and passing the date, but the state is not persisted.
- I'm not sure what is best practice for doing this. Or if it's just a bad idea.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

import * as helpers from '../../common/helpers';

export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://api.example.com`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            data: result
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <h4>Most Recent</h4>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Column 1</th>
              <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map(newRow => (

              // Here I'd like to conditionally render a row if there has been a change in day from the last row before rendering the next row.
              // ie. if previousDate != currentDate
              // <tr>
              //   <td>{helpers.getFormattedDate(newRow.time)}</td>
              //   <td></td>
              //   <td></td>
              // </tr>
              // Then render the following :

              <tr key={newRow.id}>

                <td>
                  {helpers.getFormattedTime(newRow.time)}
                </td>

                <td>
                  <Link to={`/something`}>{helpers.getFormattedNumber(newRow.value)}</Link>
                </td>

                <td>
                  {/* Some more content here */}
                </td>

              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help here would be appreciated, I'm more than a bit lost on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional rendering in React by combining two features:

1. JavaScript stops evaluating expressions with boolean operators like `&&` and `||` as soon as the value of the expression can be determined. For example, in `func1() && func2()`, the function `func2` is never called if `func1` returns a falsey (`null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`) value. Similarly, in `func1() || func2()`, `func2` is never called if `func1` returns a truthy value.
2. React does not render falsey (except `0`) values.

So a common way to do conditional rendering in React is to do something like:

```js
<div>
    { isTrue && (
        <MyConditionalComponent/>
    )}
</div>
```

Where `MyConditionalComponent` will only be rendered if `isTrue` is truthy.

In your case, since you're using a `map`, you'll probably also want to use the `Fragment` component which basically allows you to return more than a single component for an element of the `map`. Alternatively you could use a `reduce`, but for simplicity I'll just show an example with the `map`:

```js
<tbody>
  {data.map((newRow, i) => (

    <React.Fragment>
      (i !== 0 && (getDate(newRow.time) !== getDate(data[i - 1].time))) && (
        <tr>
          <td>{helpers.getFormattedDate(newRow.time)}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      )

      <tr key={newRow.id}>

        <td>
          {helpers.getFormattedTime(newRow.time)}
        </td>

        <td>
          <Link to={`/something`}>{helpers.getFormattedNumber(newRow.value)}</Link>
        </td>

        <td>
          {/* Some more content here */}
        </td>

      </tr>
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Where `getDate` would be some function that returns just the date part from a `Date` object.

Note we also make use of the second argument (`i`) of the `map` callback, which is the index of the current element to check  on the date of the previous element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map`'s 2nd argument, the index:

```
{data.map((newRow, index) => {
  const prevRow = data[index - 1];
  return (
    // Fragment is necessary because you will
    // now potentially render 2 elements
    <React.Fragment key={newRow.id}> 
      {prevRow && newRow.date !== prevRow.date && (
        <tr>
          <td>{helpers.getFormattedDate(newRow.time)}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      )} 
      <tr>
        // The rest of your component
      </tr>
    <React.Fragment>
  )
}}
```